# How does one put a link / url to the web-site's home page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In Django templates, is there a variable in the context (e.g. `{{ BASE\_URL }}`, `{{ ROOT\_URL }}`, or `{{ MEDIA\_URL }}` that one can use to link to the `home` url of a project?

I.e. if Django is running in the root of a project, the variable (let's call it R) `{{ R }}` in a template would be `/`. If the root url is a sub-folder `http://host/X/` the variable `{{ R }}` would be `/X/` (or `http://host/X/`).

It seems painfully simple, but I can't find an answer. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could give the URL configuration which you're using to handle the home page a name and use that:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
)
```

Templates:

```
<a href="{% url index %}">...
```

**UPDATE:** Newer versions of Django require quotation marks around the name of the view:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">...
```

This note in the Django Book has some tips about deploying your applications to a subdirectory:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter20/#cn43

Comment: In Django 1.5 I found I had to do <a href="{% url "index" %}">... (i.e. put the name in quotes), otherwise it complained about an empty first argument.

Answer (score 13):

I always use something like `<a href="/">` (assuming your home is at the root, of course). I seem to recall looking this up once, and couldn't find a Django variable for this path; at any rate, `/` seemed pretty easy, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

In your admin, go to "sites" and set the domain.

Pass `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to the templates in question.

Now use `{{ SITE_URL }}` in any of those templates and you're golden.

[Chapter 10 of the Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter10/) has more information than you'll need regading that context processor bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/home/'}),
```

works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In your main project's `urls.py`, check the name you have to home page

for example in my project, it is "home"

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name= "home"), 
]
```

So in the template, point to that url name

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}" <a/>
```